# Basic properties of Fourier Series. 4.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Consider the $2\pi$-periodic odd function defined on $[0,\pi]$ by $f(\theta)=\theta (\pi - \theta)$.

(b)Compute the Fourier Coefficients of $f$,  show that$$f(\theta) = \frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{k\ odd\ \ge 1}\frac{\sin(k\theta)}{k^3} $$

I calculated $\hat{f}(0)$ and it was $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$(which at the end I knew that it is wrong).But the calculation of $\hat{f}(n)$ gave me $$(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{in}) \{\frac{\pi}{-in} e^{-in\pi} + \frac{1}{n^2}(e^{-in\pi} - 1)\} + \frac{1}{2in\pi} (\pi^2 e^{-in\pi})$$(which was also wrong ),
 which I do not know how it will reach the formula that he wants? and also I do not know the importance of mentioning that the function is odd.
May be the book want us to use the following problem results, exactly letter (b) of it [Basic Properties Of Fourier Series. 2.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164411/basic-properties-of-fourier-series-2). 
For the integration by parts that we do when we are calculating the Fourier Coefficient, The following link contains the details [Integration By Parts Example.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169819/integration-by-parts-example),
Now I knew the correct answer of this question,  thanks to all who helped me and I hope this question will be a reference to questions that appear in minds before trying to solve questions like it. The newest and the most beautiful thing that I have learned from this question is adjusting the definition of the given function.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood the function. $f$ is supposed to be odd and $2\pi$-periodic, and on the interval $[0,\pi]$ is given by $f(\theta) = \theta(\pi - \theta)$. From the oddness, it follows that on the interval $[-\pi,0]$ it is given by $f(\theta) = \theta(\pi + \theta)$. In a single formula, $f(\theta) = \theta(\pi - \lvert\theta\rvert)$ for $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$, and then extend it using the periodicity.

Comment: Thank u so much your answer seems so reasonable. but am I going to calculate Fourier Series on$ [0,\pi]$or on $[-\pi, \pi]$.

Comment: Also, I think on the interval $[-\pi, 0]$ $f(\theta) = -\theta (\pi - \theta)$ not  $f(\theta) = \theta (\pi + \theta)$ as u wrote, because $f(\theta)$ is negative in this case.

Comment: How can I extend the summation of Fourier Series on$$ k\ odd\ \ge 1$$ instead of $$[-\infty , \infty]$$.

Comment: No .$f(\theta)=\theta(\pi + \theta)$ on $[-\pi , 0]$ as written before by @DanielFischer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we make f a $2-\pi$ periodic odd function (Extend $f$).

From oddness $f(-\theta)=-f(\theta)$

So on $[-\pi , 0]$ we have $$f(-(-\theta))=-(f(-\theta))=-(-\theta(\pi + \theta))=\theta(\pi + \theta)$$

$f(\theta)=\theta(\pi - |\theta|)$ on $[-\pi , \pi]$

So  $$
f(\theta)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\theta(\pi + \theta) \ \ \ \  \theta  \in [-\pi ,0]& \\ 
\theta(\pi - \theta) \ \ \ \  \theta  \in [\ \ 0 ,\pi\ ]& 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Which implies that : $$
f'(\theta)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\pi + 2\theta \ \ \ \  \theta  \in [-\pi ,0]& \\ 
\pi - 2\theta \ \ \ \  \theta  \in [\ \ 0 ,\pi\ ]& 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

To Calculate the Fouries coefficient :

$$\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta)e^{-in\theta} \ d\theta$$
Integrate by parts implies :
$$\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\frac{-f(\theta)}{in}e^{-in\theta}\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \ + \ \frac{1}{2ni\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f'(\theta)e^{-in\theta} \ d\theta=\frac{1}{2in\pi}\left( \int_{-\pi}^{0}(\pi + 2\theta)e^{-in\theta} \ d\theta + \int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi - 2\theta)e^{-in\theta}\right)$$

Which implies that : 
$$\hat{f}(n)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{4}{n^3\pi i}   & n \ is \ odd \\ 
 0 & n \ is\ even
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Finaly :
$$f\sim \sum_{n \ odd \ \ge 1}^{} \frac{4}{n^3 \pi i} e^{in\theta}$$

Then From :
$$f(\theta) \thicksim \hat{f}(0) + \sum_{n\ge1}[\hat{f}(n) + \hat{f}(-n)]\ cos n\theta + i[\hat{f}(n) - \hat{f}(-n)]\ sin n\theta. $$

You will get : $$f(\theta) = \frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n\ odd\ \ge 1}\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^3} $$

Comment: Then by substituting with the value of $\hat{f}(n)$ in the third line from below in the answer we will get the required. Thanks to all who helped me.

Comment: You're welcome .