# Integration By Parts Example.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, integration-by-parts

I have to solve this integration by parts question,
$$\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi i n}\left( \int_{-\pi}^{0}(\pi + 2\theta) e^{-in\theta}d\theta + \int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi - 2\theta) e^{-in\theta}d\theta \right). $$

I solved it and my answer was,
$$\begin{cases}
0 & \texttt{n even}, \\
\frac{-1(4\pi i n + 8)}{2\pi(in)^3} & \texttt{n odd. }
\end{cases}$$

Even though, one of my friends solved it and the answer was,$$\begin{cases}
0 & \texttt{n even}, \\
\frac{4}{i\pi(n)^3} & \texttt{n odd. }
\end{cases}$$

Could anyone participate with us in this calculation?

thanks.

Comment: I do not understand why my question is voted down, do I break any rule according to this site?

Comment: I think that the downvotes came from: "Also, I know that there are many programs for which u enter the integration that u want to calculate and they gave u the final answer, Could anyone give me a link to download these programs or at least one of them (suitable for 32bit computer)." This forum is intended for e g questions about mathematics or mathematical principles. I have upvoted your question though, as it looks OK now.

Comment: With $n=1$ your friend is right.

Comment: Did you do your calculation at first, then say that? How did you think in it? how did u know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that

$$\int_{-\pi}^{0} (\pi+2\theta)e^{-in\theta}\,d\theta \;=\; \int_{0}^{\pi} (\pi-2\theta)e^{in\theta}\,d\theta$$

the integrals become

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{0} (\pi+2\theta)e^{-in\theta}\,d\theta + \int_{0}^{\pi} (\pi-2\theta)e^{-in\theta}\,d\theta &\;=\; \int_{0}^{\pi} (\pi-2\theta)(e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta})\,d\theta \\[0.2cm]
 &\;=\; 2\int_{0}^{\pi} (\pi-2\theta)\cos(n\theta)\,d\theta. 
\end{align}$$

using $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$. 
Since

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(n\theta)\,d\theta \;=\;\left.\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n}\right|_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \;=\; 0 $$

and, integrating by parts:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\theta\cos(n\theta)\,d\theta &\;=\; \left.\frac{\theta\sin(n\theta)}{n}\right|_{\theta=0}^{\pi} - \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n}\,d\theta \\[0.3cm]
 &\;=\; 0 - \left.\left(-\frac{\cos(n\theta)}{n^{2}}\right)\right|_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \;=\; \frac{\cos(n\pi)}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{n^{2}} \;=\; \frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{n^{2}}, 
\end{align}$$

where we used $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^{n}$, you find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{0} (\pi+2\theta)e^{-in\theta}\,d\theta + \int_{0}^{\pi} (\pi-2\theta)e^{-in\theta}\,d\theta &\;=\; \frac{4(1-(-1)^{n})}{n^{2}} 
\end{align}.$$

So if $n$ is even, the integral is zero (since $(-1)^{n}=1$), whereas for $n$ odd, the integral yields $\frac{8}{n^{2}}$ (since $(-1)^{n}=-1$). This will then lead to your friend's result.