# Series Of Sines.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I want to ask:How $ \hat{f}(0) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2i\hat{f}(n)\sin(n\Theta)$ is a series of sines? 
How can I deal with $$\hat{f}(0)?$$

Do anyone have an idea?

Comment: A Fourier series usually has a sum over cosines as well, and $\hat{f}(0)$ can be thought of as the cosine term with $n = 0$.

Comment: It's a transform of an odd function.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I want it to be a series of sines not cosines.

Comment: If the function is odd, then $\hat{f}(0) = 0$, for the same reason all the other cosine coefficients are zero.

Comment: @MyGlasses I do not know what do you mean by a transform of odd function?, I have a very small knowledge about Fourier Transform, Actually the detailed question of mine is in the following link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164411/basic-properties-of-fourier-series-2

Comment: @eyeballfrog Actually the following link contain my detailed question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164411/basic-properties-of-fourier-series-2 could u please help me in letter (d) in it ?

Comment: For an odd function $a_n=0$ for all $n\geq0$, and while you have this type if your function is of the form $f=a+$odd function, that is an odd function shifted acroos $y$-axis with $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is odd, then after substituting with $n =0$ in$$\hat{f}(0) =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{-int}dt$$ we get an integration over an odd function in a symmetric interval, which equals 0.