# Effect of Symmetry of a Function on its Fourier Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, book-recommendation

Let $f$ be a $2 \pi$ Riemann integrable function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.
If the Fourier series of the function $f$ can be written as
$$f(\theta) \thicksim \hat{f}(0) + \sum_{n\ge1}[\hat{f}(n) + \hat{f}(-n)]\ \cos n\theta + i[\hat{f}(n) - \hat{f}(-n)]\ \sin n\theta. $$

If $f$ is even, then  $\hat{f}(n) = \hat{f}(-n)$, and we get a cosine series.
If $f$ is odd, then $\hat{f}(n)= -\hat{f}(-n)$, and we get a sine series.

Suppose that $f(\theta + \pi)$ = $f(\theta)$ for all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for all odd $n$.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Just compute $f(\theta + \pi)$ and then construct a series for $f(\theta + \pi) - f(\theta) = 0$. This will give you two cases to solve for, the even $n$ and the odd $n$. The even $n$ will disappear due to the $(-1)^{n} - 1$ term in your series. Hopefully you can then show that $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for odd $n$.

Comment: Do you mean by computing $f(\theta + \pi )$ to use the formula for $f(\theta)$ given in the question above? as I saw that if I try to calculate $f(\theta + \pi)$ using $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} a_{n} e^{in(\theta + \pi)}$ I will calculate $\hat{f}(n)$ first

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If $f(\theta)$ is the series above, then $f(\theta + \pi)$ is just the series with the argument $\theta$ changed to $\theta + \pi$ i.e $\cos(n \theta) \mapsto \cos(n \theta + n \pi)$ and similarly for $\sin$. Then use trig identities to simplify new trig functions.

Comment: yeah, thank u, you answered my question.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. $f(\theta + \pi) - f(\theta)$ should be a series. You should edit your post to include your working so that any further problems can be easily addressed and also so that anyone in the future who needs help on a similar problem can use your question as a reference.

Comment: I get $$f(\theta + \pi) - f(\theta) =\sum_{n\ge1} ((-1)^{n} - 1) [\hat{f}(n) + \hat{f}(-n)] cosn\theta + i\{ ((-1)^{n} -1) [\hat{f}(n) - \hat{f}(-n)]sinn\theta \}$$ and if n is even it is clear that the right hand side vanishes, what about if n is odd? could u give me a hint ?

Comment: Looks good, though I think you mean $f(\theta + \pi) - f(\theta)$ not $f(\theta) + \pi$. Also, use \sin and \cos so the names aren't italicised. Now, remember this series is equal to $0$. What happens to the $((-1)^{n} - 1)$ term when $n$ is even? $n$ odd?

Comment: ok, give me 2 minuites to think

Comment: If n is odd I will get the following formula  $$f(\theta + \pi) - f(\theta) =\sum_{n\ge1} (-2) [\hat{f}(n) + \hat{f}(-n)] \cos n\theta + i\{ (-2) [\hat{f}(n) - \hat{f}(-n)] \sin n\theta \}$$, So what shall I do?

Comment: Perfect, except that your sum should be $\sum_{n \ odd}$ as you have already shown that for even $n$ each term is $0$. Now you know that this series has to be equal to zero $\forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$, but $\sin$ and $\cos$ are only $0$ for integer values of $\pi$ and $\pi/2$ respectively. So what does that tell you about your coefficients?

Comment: It tells me that my coefficients are zero which means that $$[\hat{f}(n) + \hat{f}(-n)=0]$$, And  $$[\hat{f}(n) - \hat{f}(-n)=0]$$, Hence $$[\hat{f}(n) =- \hat{f}(-n)]$$, And  $$[\hat{f}(n) = \hat{f}(-n)]$$, Hence, $$[\hat{f}(n)=0]$$ as it is equal a positive and negative of the same number.... I think that`s it....right ?